# Laravel 8 Route not Defined Error Caused by Auth Middleware

Tags: authentication, laravel-8

I am attempting to access a route defined in my `routes/web.php` file:

```php
Route::get('/dashboard', [ConsoleController::class, 'dashboard'])->middleware('auth');
```

I am not logged in. The `Authenticate.php` middleware file attempts to redirect me back to the login page:

```php
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('');
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried using `return route('/');` in the `Authenticate.php` middleware.

My `routes/web.php` file has a default route which works fine if I go to the page manually:

```php
Route::get('/', [ConsoleController::class, 'loginForm'])->middleware('guest');
```

However, the `Authenticate.php` is causing the following error:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [] not defined.
http://localhost:8888/dashboard
```

And it points to the following line of code:

```php
public function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
{
    if (! is_null($route = $this->routes->getByName($name))) {
        return $this->toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute);
    }
    throw new RouteNotFoundException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");
}
```

I have found many similar posts on and off Stack Overflow, but none of those solutions have helped.

Am I naming my default route wrong? Can I not use this route in my `Authenticate.php` middleware? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is, you are using route() method of Laravel, which expect route name as a parameter but you are passing actual url.

In your `routes/web.php` file, add name to your route as

`Route::get('/dashboard', [ConsoleController::class, 'dashboard'])->middleware('auth')->name('dashboard');`

Then in your `Authenticate` middleware file,

```
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! Out of curiosity, I'm using the route() method in my ```Authenticate``` middleware, is there another method? I believe that code was the default content of that file.

Comment: There is anther way to doing it, `return redirect()->to('\dashboard');`.  Here you can pass your URL instead of route name. You can check Laravel docs for more information.